# Is this question really a duplicate of the one marked as such?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I'm really scratching my head trying to understand how [upgrading to full frame with just one lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101975/158710) is a duplicate of [Is there ever a right time to upgrade to full frame camera body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/70792/15871)

Sure, on the surface they're both kind of *about* whether someone should get a full frame camera. We have plenty of other similar questions that provide specifics regarding what aspects the OP is considering when trying to make such a choice, and those aren't generally marked as duplicates of [Is there ever a right time to upgrade to full frame camera body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/70792/15871)
, **which seems to be primarily, if not exclusively, about product cycles, prices, and when is the best time in terms of a camera's product life to buy one.** In other words, it is about how to buy the same camera (or its successor in a product line) at the lowest price.

[Upgrading to full frame with just one lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101975/158710) isn't remotely about product cycles, when camera bodies go on sale, etc. It's more about "How useful will a full frame camera be if my only FF lens is a 50mm f/1.8?" It seems to me this is a totally different question, although it was perhaps not asked as well as it could have been.

There may well be other questions here that are closer to [upgrading to full frame with just one lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101975/158710) than the one marked as a duplicate. It may well be that the actual question the OP asked, though not very related at all to the one marked as a duplicate, may be primarily opinion based.

**I'd really like to know what the thought process was of those who voted to close** [upgrading to full frame with just one lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101975/158710) as a duplicate of [Is there ever a right time to upgrade to full frame camera body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/70792/15871)

Answer (score 2):

You're right; the other question is focused on timing and this one focused on the "I don't have the whole system" angle. However, all of the *answers* to both of them are along the lines of: "Please check your basic assumptions about what a full frame camera system is and what it means to 'upgrade' to one." It doesn't seem *super* valuable for us to write basically those same answers over and over again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd really like to hear from those who so quickly voted to close.